# What is a good response to questions that potentially violate OP's users' privacy?

Tags: discussion, questions, privacy

I commented on a question from [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1802154/timothy-coetzee) a day or two ago, asking whether the screenshot of customer data is real data. That question was deleted (I think for moderation reasons) and I noticed he'd included the same screenshot [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18572612/working-with-information-user-clicked-from-database).

Given that the first row matches his own name, I'm inclined to think the data is real (and the individuals within are unlikely to have granted their permission to have their details published). I've asked the OP for clarification - with the purpose of asking it to be removed entirely if it is - but have had no answer.

I'm not raising the question in order to suggest that Stack Overflow is a *publisher* and thus legally liable for data protection issues (I am not a lawyer, etc). My purpose is to ask the community what our collective ethos ought to be, in the general case. For example, we could specifically put something in the Help section that requires real customer data to be anonymised prior to posting it in a Q&A site. Questions that obviously violate privacy could be closed, too, to encourage a culture of care around posters' customers' data.

I'd see this in the same light as spotting SQL injection flaws in people's posted code. I'd take the view that where we see it happening (and of course it requires an admission) then the OP should be steered towards a better path. Happily though, I've not seen it often.

Comment: For SO/SE this is covered in the [Content Policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy): *"Users may not post other people's personally identifying or confidential information, including but not limited to credit card numbers, Social Security Numbers, and driver's and other license numbers. You may not post information such as other people's passwords, usernames, phone numbers, addresses and e-mail addresses unless already publicly accessible on the Web."* So if these are real, they should not be posted.

Comment: Ah, I'd missed that @Bart - thanks. I'll ping the original question with a note to this discussion.

Comment: @Andre: Bart's comment is very helpful, but arguably there are several possible answers, in the form "Here's how we should respond". One approach is close voting, but I'm open to whatever changes the culture - rather like we're discouraging help vampirism, I guess. Bad practices don't disappear overnight `:)`.

Comment: @halfer I have attempted to address that in the answer.

Comment: My guess would be the data isn't real. I don't think phone numbers can start with a 0.

Comment: The data looks real. If you google the phone numbers they come up with the people's names. They don't start with zero because they aren't in the United States -- as you can see from the email suffixes. Google the first # to see.

Comment: The question has been deleted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Our collective ethos doesn't matter all that much in this case. In [the content policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy) of Stack Exchange, under "Identity Theft and Privacy" the following is stated:

> Users may not post other people's personally identifying or confidential information, including but not limited to credit card numbers, Social Security Numbers, and driver's and other license numbers. You may not post information such as other people's passwords, usernames, phone numbers, addresses and e-mail addresses unless already publicly accessible on the Web.

So if that data is real and not already publicly available, the OP is simply not allowed to post it.

If you have any reasonable suspicion that this is real, rather than waiting for the OP's response, flag it for moderator attention. Use the "other" option and explain what the problem is. Editing it out won't do much. Data might have to be purged at a deeper level, so even the revision history doesn't lead to it any more.

Comment: I'd previously hesitated to flag it, since I felt that the privacy of the OP's users (as opposed to our fellow users here) would be regarded as "someone else's legal problem". However I am emboldened by your advice, so I've reported it - thank you.

Comment: FWIW I have done the same.

Comment: @halfer - I deleted this one like I did the last, and had a ping in with the devs to burn that older post. I'll add this new post to that request. I'm not sure how to salvage the question without that data.